# Viewing PDF file in visual C++ GUI

Tags: visual-c++, pdf, user-interface

I am currently using the Adobe PDF reader control on my GUI and am viewing PDF's with the following code:

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
axAcroPDF1->src=openFileDialog1->FileName;
```

This code is inside of a button pressed function so that when I press the button a file browser opens, when the PDF is selected it opens and can be viewed on the GUI.

Is there a way of automatically opening the PDF every time the GUI is launched so that I do not have to manually browse and find the PDF file?

Comment: I'm assuming your GUI has an On Activate event of some sorts? Can't you just set the src of your Acrobat control to the correct path when that happens?

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! Is there any way for me to run this from the resources? If I add the PDF file to the resources what would I change the code to to open the file?

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer so you can accept it and people can see the answer if they're looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the place to add code to the On Activate event of your UI. In that location set the src property of the Adobe Acrobat control to the path of the file you want to open.

The following StackOverflow question and answer should give you everything you need to embed elements into an exe and find them afterwards with FindResource:
[Visual C++ Get a resource's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542115/visual-c-get-a-resources-path)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have done as shown on in the link you had provided, I added the PDF to the resources using the existing item option and specified my source as "Resources/test.pdf", the GUI compiled however the file was not found as when I press the button (which is the event under which this is specified) nothing loads.

Comment: Did it actually find the resource? I'm guessing that the calls you use to get the resource should return something and probably either return nil or throw an exception if nothing is returned? I'd see first of all whether that isn't the problem. If there resource is indeed found it could be that your control only works if the resource is an actual file (which it might not be as a resource), in which case you might have to extract it to a temp folder first, and then pass the path to the temp folder location to your control...